# Prove the inequality $xyz^3 \leq 27(\frac{x+y+z}{5})^5$.

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $x,y,z>0$, prove the inequality $xyz^3 \leq 27(\frac{x+y+z}{5})^5$.
Any ideas? I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $f(x,y,z) = 27 \left( \frac{x+y+z}{5} \right)^5 - x y z^3$. Then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y,z) = 27 \left(\frac{x+y+z}{5}\right)^4 - y z^3$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y,z) = 27 \left(\frac{x+y+z}{5}\right)^4 - x z^3$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,z) = 27 \left(\frac{x+y+z}{5}\right)^4 - 3 x y z^2$$
At a minimum these all should equal $0$, so $yz^3 = xz^3 = 3x y z^2$, which gives us $x=y$ and $z=3x$. Plugging these in the inequality shows that the equality is attained at these points. One also has to check the boundary, i.e. when one or two or three of the variables is $0$, but this is trivial.

Comment: Thanks! Do we still have to check the boundary? because it is specified that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are not equal to zero

Comment: @BenJames: Yes we do, checking that the derivative is zero does not exclude the possibility that the function gets small at the boundary. In fact we also have to check the behaviour at infinity.

Comment: Do we also have to show that the critical point is a minimum and not a maximum or saddle point?

Comment: @BenJames: No. It is enough to know that all maximums and minimums are among the critical points or the boundary.

Comment: So how do we know that the value $f(x,x,3x)$ is not a maximum? In your answer haven't you just found that it is the value of a critical point? Not necessarily a minimum value?

Comment: Or do we evaluate all maximums and minimums and just pick the minimum one? And the minimum one is at the point (x,x,3x).

Comment: @BenJames: Yes, we evaluate every critical point. That is every maximum and minimum and saddle point. And then we evaluate every boundary point. And finally we check what happens at infinity. And if all of these yield that the result is greater than $0$, then we know that it must hold everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:  Checking when equality is obtained, it makes sense to substitute $z = 3a$.  Then apply AM-GM to the simplified inequality.